# Downgrade libstdc++.so.6 to version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20'

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, libraries, cross-compilation, c++

I am trying to cross-compile dlib using Raspberry Pi's toolchain, with the SD card mounted to my linux Host.

After successful build and install, I start my Pi, and run

```
python -c 'import dlib'
```

This is the error output:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by dlib/dlib.so)
```

When I run it on my Raspberrry Pi, this is what I get:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

What's going on? How can I fix this?  On my Pi, `libstdc++`is already at its newest version.

Is this an issue with my HOST machine, which as expected, has the `GLIBCXX_3.4.22` string.

If possible, can I downgrade libstdc++ on my host machine so that the maximum version it supports is 3.4.20? How?

**Host**:

OS: Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit (amd64)

Cross-Compilation environment: Official toolchain hosted here: [Raspberry Pi Tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian)

Another thing that might help is that I am mounting the SD card (which contains the Raspbian OS) to my host machine, and then using a cmake toolchain file to set the `sysroot` to the location of the SD card.

Output of `dpkg -l|grep 'gcc.*arm'`:

`abhishek@K  ~/rpi 
$ dpkg -l|grep 'gcc.*arm'
ii  gcc-6-arm-linux-gnueabihf                       6.3.0-12ubuntu2cross1                         amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-6-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base:amd64            6.3.0-12ubuntu2cross1                         amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf                         4:6.3.0-2ubuntu1                              amd64        GNU C compiler for the armhf architecture
ii  libgcc-6-dev-armhf-cross                        6.3.0-12ubuntu2cross1                         all          GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1-armhf-cross                             1:6.3.0-12ubuntu2cross1                       all          GCC support library`

**Note**: I posted it on the raspberry SE website, but was suggested to move the question.

Comment: Your host machine is probably an i386 or amd64 machine. Raspberry Pi is an arm. Thus, the compilation surely doesn't happen against the glibc++ of your host machine. As you write, there is a cross-compilation environment on it, this cross-compilation environtment has its own, arm-based glibc++, and you have to synchronize its version to your raspberry pi's. But you didn't write anything about your cross compilation environment and about your host OS. What is that? The simplest solution would be to downgrade your cross-compilation environment for that. Or you could take the .22 into your pi.

Comment: Or you could link the glibc++ statically into your binary, if it is feasible. There are so many possible solutions, I can't even count them! But to decide, which one should I answer you, you should give more info.

Comment: @peterh Thank you, Sir. I have updated the question. Hope that provides the info required to provide a feasible solution. I can try copying the glibc++ to the Pi. That seems like the easiest option to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks :-) Here lies another important thing: we re good in Linux, but typically not very good in raspberry. The people of the raspberry site, exactly the opposite :-) But there is some cross-section between us. For example, I checked this raspberry pi tools first time in my life. What I see on the spot: it is a 4 year old project, it is unlikely to have such a new library. I downloaded now the libstdc++ in it, and I see that it has symbols only until **`GLIBCXX_3.4.19`** . Anything what you compile with this library, which is reachable on that github link,

Comment: [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/blob/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc%2B%2B.so.6.0.19), surely shouldn't want a GLIBCXX_3.4.22 symbol. It is possible (but unlikely) that it won't compile with that old glibc++, but it can't await a symbol, whose existence is unknown for him.

Comment: Right! That cross-section can help in this situation, you are right about that.

Right. Does this mean that as new projects come along, and since they wanna support the state-of-the-art tech, they'd probably need higher versions of the library, which as it happens, haven't been made available for the Pi?

Comment: Are you sure, that your system doesn't contain somewhere an arm-compiled 3.4.22 glibc++ version in the link path? The compilation script of Python modules aren't very nice, they don't like to say, what are they doing now. Maybe you have some debian/ubuntu-based cross-gcc, installed by apt, which is somehow in your link path?

Comment: Ok, but the problem is probably on your host system configuration, and not on your raspberry pi configuration, and probably also the raspberry pi people has seen this, this is why they've sent you here. `dpkg -l|grep 'gcc.*arm'` what says?

Comment: Maybe. I think you are right. This seems like some `cross-gcc` available at apt. I ran it. It is in the bin directory. I have also added the output of that command at the end of the question.

Comment: The simplest way is to purging out all of the debian/ubuntu cross-arm packages. `dpkg -l|grep arm`, you will see the list. Purge them all. You may try to play a little bit with the compilation script of that python library, to guarantee that it doesn't do any bad. And to check, from where exactly it gets its c++ libraries.

Comment: I have purged all of them. Reading the python script, https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/setup.py

Thank you for the help. Let me see if it works now.

Comment: What does `cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory` signify? The C compiler fails, and cmake exits.

Comment: It's an open issue here. I see: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/issues/50

Comment: Then I suspected it well. It didn't use your raspberry pi libraries, it found only your debian packages. Now you removed them, now it absolutely won't compile. The `crt1.o` is a simple object file, it will be some header (or tail) of all compiled binaries, and it contains only some very trivial functions what is used internally by all processes compiled by the gcc. You should make it sure, that it uses the linking path of your raspberry pi toolkit. However, this toolkit seems to be a particularly ancient one (4 years, not yesterday), maybe you could hunt somewhere a more recent crosschain.

Comment: The toolchain can produce probably still working code for your raspberry pi, because it is for probably some raspberry pi which were recent 4 years ago. And linuxes, including your current raspberry pi, tend to be backward compatible. But this ancient toolchain is probably partially incompatible with your current ubuntu.

Comment: All right. Ancient toolchain lol :P

Anyway, I believe you are right. I think I need to find a new cross-compiling toolchain, like you said. Hopefully that would solve the issue. Also, the other linaro cross-compiler (also in that repo) does compile the project, but again gives the wrong glibc++ error. Something's messing up the path from which libraries are included.

Comment: Probably you could make it working also on this newer ubuntu, because also the Ubuntu tends to be backward compatible. Probably you should have to set up some gcc flags manually, or only your install script weren't very okay. Probably it would be easy to create a deb package from that toolchain which is installable by `dpkg -i` everywhere and works correctly. Or you could play with the gcc environment variables (`LD_LINK_PATH` and similar). Check the install instructions of the toolchain, if there is, you may try to reinstall it accordingly.

Comment: @peterh That toolchain has it's own `sysroot` folder, which I can use to install the python library to and then use rsync or something to go about it. 

However, dlib requires some jpeg and png and other libararies, which AFAIK, can be installed using apt.

But, how can I get those libraries on my Host? Can I just copy the installed binaries from my Pi to this supposed sysroot folder of the cross-compiler?